# Return a modified viewModel to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanna do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Foo foo)
{
    foo.Name = "modified";

    return View(foo);
}
```

but when my view is rendered, it always has the old values! How can I modify and return? Must I clear the ModelState everytime?

---

My view:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Foo


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

Comment: @Shyju It only works to me if I use 'ModelState.Clear();' before setting the modified properties.

Comment: something else is happening then. that should work fine.

Comment: Well, I created a new mvc 3 and mvc 4 projects, and it doestn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be expected behavior because the "normal" scenario where you send back the same model to the view is when the model has errors.

See:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

Answer (score 1):

MVC uses ModelState on postback to populate the View, not the passed model. To update a single field before returning to the view try something like this:

```
var newVal = new ValueProviderResult("updated value", "updated value", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
ModelState.SetModelValue("MyFieldName", newVal);
```

More info here: [ModelStateDictionary.SetModelValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.setmodelvalue?view=aspnetcore-1.0)

Comment: Microsoft's documentation is dense at the best of times but the stuff on [ValueProviderResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.valueproviderresult?view=aspnetcore-1.0) is inpenetrable! All I wanted to do was set a boolean value in the model when returning it following a failed POST. Got there in the end but it was painful!