# MVC 3 The View is not being refreshed after model submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strange problem with my view in the MVC 3 project. I have a standard view for data editing (created using the template). When I submits the form, I change the `Name` property, but after I came back to the browser from the controller I still see the `lorem` value. Why ?

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        <input type="submit" value="Save"  />
    }


    public ViewResult EditUserData(int id)
    {
        [...]
        UserData model = new UserData();
        model.Name = "lorem";            

        return View("~/Views/UserDetails.cshtml", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult EditUserData(UserData model)
    {
        model.Name = "ipsum";
        return View("~/Views/UserDetails.cshtml", model);    
    }

public class ControlUserData
{
    [...]

    [Required]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "UserNameFirst")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did the post action being hit ? visual studio breakpoints ??

Comment: @Shyju Yes, the debugger invokes the HttpPost's Action after I hit the submit button

Comment: Why `View("~/Views/UserDetails.cshtml", Model)` instead of putting it in the shared directory and doing `View("UserDetails", Model)`?

Comment: @Tony : Is the provided code is same as what you have ( for the post action method) ? Do you have ModelState.IsValid property checking statement ??

Comment: @Erik Philips the view's path is modified in my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the value from the `ModelState` if you want to modify it in a post/get:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult EditUserData(UserData model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Name");
    model.Name = "ipsum";
    return View("~/Views/UserDetails.cshtml", model);    
}
```

This is the built in MVC behavoir: all the `Html.Helpers` prefers the values in the `ModelState` collection over the actual model values.

There is a good article about this here: [ASP.NET MVC Postbacks and HtmlHelper Controls ignoring Model Changes](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes).

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.  MVC is assuming that you want to show what the user initially submitted when processing a post action.  See [this related stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920517/return-a-modified-viewmodel-to-view/10920956#10920956).

Answer (score 0):

Just a small Edit... for refreshing the entire Model

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult EditUserData(UserData model)
{
   UserData newmodel = new UserData();
   ModelState.Clear();
   model = newmodel;
   return View("~/Views/UserDetails.cshtml", model);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating ModelState (on postback the View uses this collection, not the passed model) for a single field has an easier workaround. Here's what I just did to update a specific field before returning to the same view:

```
var newVal = new ValueProviderResult("updated value", "updated value", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
ModelState.SetModelValue("MyFieldName", newVal);
```

Depending on the version of .NET/MVC you're using, [ModelStateDictionary.SetModelValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.setmodelvalue?view=aspnetcore-1.0) has other, simpler, overloads.